# Starting a company using this patent

Tags: claims, wo2003023674a1

In reference to the patent: [WO2003023674A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2003023674A1)

The mobile application that I am working on uses QR codes to store personal credit card information, and I'd like to know whether this would make me unable to continue my work on my start-up business without being sued.

The first claim is as follows:

> What is claimed is:
>
> 1. A system for credit card payment using barcode and mobile phone device comprising: a mobile phone device storing a barcode data required for a credit card payment (in it), and including a display part for display of said barcode data thereon; a barcode reader device reading the barcode displayed on the display part of said mobile phone device; and a credit card validation device, being connected to said barcode reader device, fetching the credit card payment information data from the barcode which is read by said barcode reader device, transmits said information to a credit card VAN server, and then, receives a credit card payment authentication signal from said credit card VAN server.

What does this mean in laymen's terms?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother too much about this patent application. A quick look in Espacenet showed that it was not filed in any major country in the world (maybe only in South-Korea). Further, this is only a WO publication, which means that this application itself is not a granted patent.
I should encourage you to look at the search report that was issued in this application. May be this search report cites some older patents (reasons of which the current applicants did not pursue their efforts).

Answer (score 0):

This would best be discussed by a patent attorney to keep you from being sued. However, you would need to find a difference between Quick Response and Barcodes.